# Bootstrap popover displays title but not content on dynamic control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ASP.NET project using .NET 4.5 and VisualBasic with Bootstrap 3.7. On a particular page a dynamic html table is created in the `MainContent` container of the page based on a selection the user makes. The data for that table is drawn from a SQL Server database. In selected cells of the table an image is added (dynamically at the same time the table is created) with a javascript function call to create and open a bootstrap popover. The javascript function is located inside the `MainContent` container of the page. 3 parameters are sent to the function - the id of the image, the title, and content applicable to this image. All 3 values are sent as string values.

The popover works exactly as I expect it to except it does not populate the content. As I click from 1 popover image to another the appropriate title for each different popover is displayed and the popover is located in the correct location. I know the data is sent and received by the javascript function. If in the JavaScript function I change `document.getElementById(ctrlTransfer)` to `'image'` the popover displays both the correct title **and** content. (It is not positioned by the particular popover image that was clicked but instead, by the 1st non-dynamic image on the page. Also, clicking on other popover images does not change the title or content when `'image'` has been substituted.)

Here is the JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function DisplayTransferValues(TransferControl, TransferTitle, TransferValue) {
      if (TransferTitle != 'undefined') {
         var ctrlTransfer = 'MainContent_' + TransferControl;

         $document.getElementById(ctrlTransfer)).popover({
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            title: TransferTitle,
            content: TransferValue,
         }).popover("show");
      }
   }
</script>
```

The html table is created by a call to an ASP.NET sub (in an independent code module in the project) that selectively places a popover image in certain cells in the table.

The code for creating the images for the popover follows:

```
Dim ibnTrnsfr As ImageButton = New ImageButton
ibnTrnsfr.ID = "ibnTrnsfr" & strCntrlCounter
ibnTrnsfr.Height = 12
ibnTrnsfr.Width = 12

If Not arrScheming(intRow, intCol, 25).Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
   ibnTrnsfr.ImageUrl = "/Images/TransferOutBlue4.png"
   strTransfrOut = "Transfer Out of " & strCntrlCounter
   ibnTrnsfr.OnClientClick = "DisplayTransferValues('" & ibnTrnsfr.ID & "', '" & strTrnsfrOut & "', '" & arrScheming(intRow, intCol, 25) & "'); return false;"
ElseIf Not arrScheming(intRow, intCol, 26).Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
   ibnTrnsfr.ImageUrl = "/Images/TransferOutBlue4.png"
   strTransfrIn = "Transfer into " & strCntrlCounter
   ibnTrnsfr.OnClientClick = "DisplayTransferValues('" & ibnTrnsfr.ID & "', '" & strTrnsfrIn & "', '" & arrScheming(intRow, intCol, 26) & "'); return false;"
End If
```

Additional code in the page code behind actually adds this image to the table cell.

Steps I have already taken:

1. Added a function within the DisplayTransferValues function to receive data for content and populate.
2. Added a delay to DisplayTransferValues for loading time.
3. Switched the order of "TransferTitle" and "TransferValue" in the parameters sent to the function. It successfully loads the correct data from TransferValue into the title area of the popover.

I am looking to have both the title and content populated in the popover.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found sometimes styles for a parent element can interfere with html inside the popover. Simply adding `container: 'body',` fixed the issue:

`<script type="text/javascript">
   function DisplayTransferValues(TransferControl, TransferTitle, TransferValue) {
      if (TransferTitle != 'undefined') {
         var ctrlTransfer = 'MainContent_' + TransferControl;

         $document.getElementById(ctrlTransfer)).popover({
            container: ' body',
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some additional research and found at getbootstrap.com sometimes styles for a parent element can interfere with html inside the popover. Simply adding container: 'body', fixed the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function DisplayTransferValues(TransferControl, TransferTitle, TransferValue) {
      if (TransferTitle != 'undefined') {
         var ctrlTransfer = 'MainContent_' + TransferControl;
         $document.getElementById(ctrlTransfer)).popover({
            container: ' body',
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            title: TransferTitle,
            content: TransferValue,
         }).popover("show");
      }
   }
</script>
```

Now both the Title and the Content are populated correctly in the Bootstrap Popover.